# Listview.separated lags when put inside column

Tags: flutter

I am trying to show a list of my contacts during the invite process, which is working fine but the only issue is that if I show only the futurebuilder, there is no lag.

But if I incorporate textfield and column, a lag of 4-5 seconds is there for every change. Please help.

I use fastContacts package to fetch data and there is no lag when only futurebuilder is used inside body, its only if I use futurebuilder inside column, the lag appears.

```
  getContacts() async {
    FirebaseAnalytics.instance
        .logEvent(name: AnalyticsEvent.CONTACTS_REQUESTED);
    try {
      contacts = ContactsController.getContacts();
      fullContactList = await contacts!;
      FirebaseAnalytics.instance
          .logEvent(name: AnalyticsEvent.CONTACTS_SUCCESS);
    } catch (e) {
      FirebaseAnalytics.instance.logEvent(name: AnalyticsEvent.CONTACTS_FAILED);
      log.d("$className: GetContacts(): Failed to get contacts");
    }
  }


  filterContacts(String searchText) async {
    List<Contact> filteredContacts = [];
    if (searchText.trim().isEmpty) {
      filteredContacts = fullContactList;
    } else {
      filteredContacts = fullContactList
          .where((element) => element.displayName
              .toLowerCase()
              .contains(searchText.toLowerCase()))
          .toList();
    }
    setState(() {
      contacts = Future.value(filteredContacts);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.orange.shade700,
        title: Text(
          "Add atleast $maxUserInviteCount friends",
          style: const TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
      ),
      floatingActionButton: ElevatedButton(
        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 90, vertical: 8),
            backgroundColor: Colors.orange.shade700),
        onPressed: () {
          if (userInvitedCount < maxUserInviteCount) {
            UtilityFunctions.createToast(context,
                "Add atleast ${maxUserInviteCount - userInvitedCount} more friends!");
            return;
          }
          Navigator.pushNamed(context, RouteName.OnboardingHowItWorks);
        },
        child: const Text(
          "Next",
          style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.white),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Column(
        children: [
          TextField(
            controller: _searchController,
            onChanged: (value) {
              setState(() {
                searchText = value;
              });
              filterContacts(searchText);
            },
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              hintText: "Search institute name...",
              hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
              prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search, color: Colors.grey),
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(7.0)),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          FutureBuilder<List<Contact>>(
            future: contacts,
            builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return const Center(
                  child: Text("Error Fetching Contacts! Check Permissions",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.grey,
                        fontSize: 16,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      )),
                );
              }
              if (snapshot.data == null) {
                return const Center(
                  child:
                      SizedBox(height: 50, child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
                );
              }

              if (snapshot.data.length == 0) {
                return const Center(
                  child: SizedBox(
                    height: 50,
                    child: Text("Error Fetching Contacts! Check Permissions"),
                  ),
                );
              }
              return Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Expanded(
                  child: ListView.separated(
                      primary: false,
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                      separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return Divider(
                          color: Colors.grey.shade300,
                          thickness: 1,
                        );
                      },
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        Contact contact = snapshot.data![index];
                        return AddFriendLineItemWidget(
                          user: OnboardingUser.fromContacts(contact),
                          isContact: true,
                          isFriend: false,
                          loggedInUser: currentUser,
                          increaseUserInviteCount: () {
                            setState(() {
                              userInvitedCount++;
                            });
                          },
                        );
                      }),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```